# SOAP Envelope can not have children other than SOAP Header and Body

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

With the update to version 4.6.0 wso2esb, the error began to occur:

org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: SOAP Envelope can not have children other than SOAP Header and Body

When using security services.

How do I resolve the error?

Comment: when this update comes out?   https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1777

Comment: look this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343441/error-in-wso2-esb-when-calling-service-without-header-element